# My ASP.NET Core site always routes to the default controller and action. Could this be a server configuration issue?

Tags: asp.net-core, routes

I am very new to ASP.NET to the point where I am still trying to get the default template to work on an IIS server. When I have the site deployed to IIS express everything functions fine. When I publish to an IIS server the site loads fine to the default route, But none of my action attributes work. So I cannot navigate to any other page unless I change the Route template to another default page.

I have tried getting manually typing in the URLs and they still redirect to the default route.

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
   routes.MapRoute(
     name: "default",
     template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Contact}/{id?}");
});
```

Comment: Is that route posted your default route?

Comment: Sorry that was for example. The Default is supposed to be "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}". If I want to see the Contact page. I have to change the action to Contact and Republish to the file system

Comment: The route is fine. There's some other issue at play.

Comment: Share us detail steps to reproduce your issue with built-in asp.net core template. Or, you could share us a mini demo to reproduce your issue.